# Как изменять размер массива?

Tags: c++

Такая проблема: у меня не получается изменять размер массива в аргументе функции. Есть функция begin и два case'a. В одном case создается двухмерный массив 5*5, а во втором case создается двухмерный массив 3*3. И есть функция begin, которая должна принимать массив, с учетом какой case выбран. И получается так, что у меня код работает только для второго case'a, в котором создается массив 3*3. Как сделать функцию begin многофункциональной? Чтоб она могла принимать указатель на массив с размерностью 8*8, 15*15 и т.д.?

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void begin(int (*parr)[3]){
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            parr[i][j] = rand()%10-1;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%4i",parr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    time_t t; srand(time(&t));
    cout << "Select menu: ";
    char n;
    cin >> n;
    switch(n){
        case '1':{
            int arr[5][5],c,d;
            begin(arr);
            break;
        }
        case '2':{
            int arr[3][3],c,d;
            begin(arr);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В твоём случае подойдёт

```
template <size_t n> void begin(int (&arr)[n][n]);
```

https://ideone.com/pE6PVf

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <size_t n> void print(int (&a)[n][n])
{
  for (size_t q=0; q<n; ++q)
  {
    for (size_t w=0; w<n; ++w)
      cout << a[q][w] << ' ';

    cout << endl;
  }

  cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int a[][2] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
  int b[][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};

  print(a);
  print(b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может, все же `template <size_t n> void begin(int (&arr)[n][n]);`?

Comment: @Harry, да, исправил. Спасибр.

Comment: А что произойдет при такой записи? Чему равен n?

Comment: @Евгений, в первой ветке 5, во второй 3.

Comment: Всм? То есть массив может быть как 5*5, то 3*3?

Comment: @Евгений, https://ideone.com/pE6PVf.

Comment: Да, все получилось. Спасибо. Но как это работает? Объясните) если не сложно)

Comment: @Евгений, как обычно с шаблонами - под каждый размер компилятор создаёт отдельную функцию. Тут где-то был разбор этой конструкции (конкретно с массивом).

Answer (score 2):

Во первых вы лишний раз проходите по циклу в функции, во вторых  в теле switch объявляете лишние переменные. И лучше двумерный массив передать в функцию по указателю на первый элемент и обращаться с ним как к одномерным. Но также нужно передать и размеры строк и столбцов, а если функцию будете использовать только для квадратных матриц, то можно один размер передать. Вот другой вариант с вашим кодом:

```
void begin(int* parr, const size_t n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {            
            parr[i * n + j] = rand() % 10 - 1;
            printf("%4i", parr[i * n + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}

int main()
{
    time_t t; srand(time(&t));
    cout << "Select menu: ";
    char n;
    cin >> n;
    switch (n) {
    case '1': {
        int arr[5][5];
        begin(arr[0], 5);
        break;
    }
    case '2': {
        int arr[3][3];
        begin(arr[0], 3);
        break;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я бы просто `arr` передал, а не `arr[0]`. Хотя оба варианта верные.

Comment: @Qwertiy, просто  arr  не будет указателем

Comment: Так приведётся же)